# how to target ninth position of a string

Tags: xml, xslt

hii all can any one please help me

```
 <block2>

  <receiverAddress>BKTRUS33XBRD</receiverAddress>

  </block2>
```

in the above receiver address if x is presented in the ninth position we need to take 1 to 8 digits othervise if x is not presented in ninth position we need to trim last letter of that string

output if x is 9 position is there: **BKTRUS33**
if x is not present in ninth position :**BKTRUS33XBR**

how to do in xslt

Comment: Use XPath string functions. You could start with `substring` http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring

Comment: Well... XSLT uses XPath.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that doesn't have any XSLT conditional instructions and shows the use of the `substring()` and `string-length()` standard XPath functions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="receiverAddress[substring(.,9,1)='X']">
     <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,8)"/>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="receiverAddress[not(substring(.,9,1)='X')]">
     <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,string-length() -1)"/>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document:**

```
<block2>
    <receiverAddress>BKTRUS33XBRD</receiverAddress>
    <receiverAddress>BKTRUS33YBRD</receiverAddress>
</block2>
```

**produces the wanted, correct results:**

```
BKTRUS33
BKTRUS33YBR
```

**Do note:**

1. The use of the standard XPath function **[`substring()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring)**.
2. How the standard XPath 1.0 functions **[`substring()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring)** and **[`string-length()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string-length)** are used together in order to locate/exclude a string at the end of another string.
3. You could use in XPath 2.0 the standard XPath 2.0 function **[`ends-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-ends-with)** .
4. How pattern matching is used so that no XSLT conditional instructions are necessary inside the templates.